# IntelliJ Idea not able to detect Java JDK Path

Tags: java, openjdk, jdk, intellij

I have `openjdk 11.0.4.1` Installed In my System
[image: Picture showing my installation of Java from Terminal]

I'm trying to do development in java using `IntellijIDEA` IDE of Jetbrains.
Whenever I try to start a new JAVA project I see no SDK in SDK path.
[image: Image showing IntellijIdea indicating no SDK]

So, naturally I tried to add my exisiting installation of JAVA to IntellijIdea.

- I navigated to the folder `/usr/lib/jvm`.
- Selected the folder `java-11-openjdk-amd64` which was inside it.
- After I press `OK` This error pops up telling me this is a JRE not a JDK.
  [image: Popup showing my error]

#### Please help me finding the correct location of JDK in my system..

Comment: Hello. Please do not show pictures of just text. Cut and paste the text in the body of the question.  For example your first screen.

Comment: @David from the next time I will do it

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, Oracle Java and OpenJava are very different. https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/